# iOS App crashes when user denies permission to Photos after Move & Scale in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the default UIImagePickerController with allowsEditing set to YES for taking photo. When the user moves and scales the photo, the OS asks for access to 'Photos'.
The app crashes if the user denies access.

```
- (void)openCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.editing = YES;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method goes like

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (!image) {
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }

    self.profileImage = image;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Crash message:

```
*** This application is not allowed to access Photo data.
```

I'm wondering why it should ask for access to Photos in the first place.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Tested the case with TweetBot app. Crashes there also. Seems to be an OS issue.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the "Photos" permission before presenting the camera since you allow editing which appears to require access to photos.

Comment: Do you fine any solution of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Assets Framework to test if your app is allowed to access photo data.

```
  ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

  if(status==ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        ..your code...
  }
```